# Is it safe to use multiple instance of android BillingClient in an app?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am developing an android SDK and I need to query user's existing subscriptions through BillingClient purchased before installation of my SDK. I am planning to do it by using BillingClient.getPurchases() method but I don't know if the application has any active and connected BillingClient at that time. So I will create a BillingClient object first and use this client to query existing purchases. I don't want to affect any in app purchase process of application when doing this. Is it safe to use multiple instance of BillingClient at the same time ?

```
BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(EmptyActivity.this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() ==  BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Purchase.PurchasesResult result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                    for (int i=0; i<result.getPurchasesList().size();i++) {
                        Purchase purchase = result.getPurchasesList().get(i);
                        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                            purchases.add(purchase);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/53111773/1028256